# Borsh serializing a nested object for a Solana transaction instruction

Tags: web3.js, solang

I have a Solidity function:

```
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 result = a + b;
        return result;
    }
```

That I've migrated over to Solana using solang. I want to call the `add()` function in a NodeJS script. It seems I need to serialize the call using the [borsh serializer](https://github.com/near/borsh-js) package.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to create the required schema for this Solana transaction instruction object:

```
   const num1 = 10;
   const num2 = 20;
   const transcationInstruction = {
      add: {
        num1,
        num2,
      },
    }
```

For what it's worth, I am trying to follow [this example](https://github.com/near/borsh-js#deserializing-an-object) from from the GitHub page. But, I can't quite grasp how to serialize a nested JSON object.

The end goal is I want to define a transaction instruction like so:

```
  const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      { pubkey: payerKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true },
      { pubkey: programAccountId, isSigner: false },
    ],
    programId: programAccountId,
    data: encodedInstruction,
  });
```

**WHERE**

`encodedInstruction` is the borsh serialized transaction instruction for the `add(num1, num2)` function in the Solana smart contract.

Thus, I reach out for help. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

I owe you one.

Answer (score 0):

Typically an instruction is serialized as an `enum`, ie:

```
const schema = { enum: [{ struct: { add: { struct: { num1: 'u64', num2: 'u64' } }}}] };
```

Which you can serialize by running:

```
const encoded = borsh.serialize(schema, {add: { num1: 10, num2: 20 } });
```

This is according to the examples in the README. In your program you should double-check that the bytes are correct.

Comment: Thank you @Jon C! Will try your suggestion today!